# flutter: get documents by query where in collections

Tags: jquery, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called "Users" where each document in this collection has the data of one user, but in every document I create 2 collections "Userdata" and "Friendslist" and inside UserData 2 document "PrivateData" and "PublicData"  as you can see in the image below:

[image]

and inside publicData the document userName

[image]

the question is : how can I get just the data of one user by his username ?

I tried

```
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("Users/*/UserData")
                .where(
                  'UserName',
                  isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: cquery,
                  isLessThan: cquery.substring(0, cquery.length - 1) +
                      String.fromCharCode(
                          cquery.codeUnitAt(cquery.length - 1) + 1),
                  isNotEqualTo: user.name,
                )
                .get();
```

but I didn't work and got just a empty list from firebase!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All data loading from Firestore is shallow, so there is no way to automatically get the data from the subcollections. You will have to perform an additional read for each subcollection, based on the document IDs in the `QuerySnapshot`.

```
querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) async {
  var privateRef = doc.reference.collection("UserData").doc("privateData");
  var privateDoc = await privateRef.get();
});
```